How to get Microsoft Stream Video link. Which is formatted like "https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/VIDEO_ID"
Previously,there is a Share option below the video in microsoft steam. While copying the link it is in the format "https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/VIDEO_ID". Now, it is not in that format, to achive the above format i follwed this linkMicrosoft.But after following those steps i got an error message like this.Error image. Can anyone tell me how to get the link, I thanked to you in advance.
My requirement is play microsoft stream video in power apps. For this i need to get microsoft stream video link which is formatted like this "https://web.microsoftstream.com/video/VIDEO_ID".How to get the link

There is Direct control in PowerApps apps, named as Stream video you can configure it to play video directly
